# Connect On-Premise Server with SQS through VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, endpoint, on-premises-instances

I'd like to communicate with SQS from an on-premise server without going over the open internet. I have a Transit Gateway that connects my VPC to the corporate network. I see that a VPC endpoint will allow resources inside the VPC to connect to SQS. However, I'm not sure if I can reach the VPC endpoint from outside the VPC. Is there a way I can route requests from the on-premise server to SQS through my VPC endpoint?

I have not tried anything yet but am looking for guidance.

Comment: Route 53 to setup an endpoint?

Comment: AWS direct connect seems like it can help with this too https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/

Comment: You need: [Resolving DNS queries between VPCs and your network - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver-overview-DSN-queries-to-vpc.html)